# is it possible in php to get a list of classes that use a particular trait?

Tags: php, traits

I want to get a list of classes that use a certain trait, eg:

```
trait Baz { }

class Foo { use Baz; }

class Bar { use Baz; }


$classes = getClassesThatUseTrait('Baz');

// $classes is ['Foo', 'Bar']
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
trait foo { }

class bar {
  use foo;
}

class bar2 {
}

$trait = 'foo';

// get user defined classes
$definedClasses = array_filter(
   get_declared_classes(),
   function($className) {
       return !call_user_func(
           array(new ReflectionClass($className), 'isInternal')
       );
   }
);

// select only classes that use trait $trait    
$classes = array_filter(
   $definedClasses,
   function($className) use($trait) {
     $traits = class_uses($className);
     return isset($traits[$trait]);
   }
);

var_dump($classes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reflection package has these method for working with traits:

- `ReflectionClass::getTraitAliases`
- `ReflectionClass::getTraitNames`
- `ReflectionClass::getTraits`
- `ReflectionClass::isTrait`

There is no "get all classes that use trait X" method.

If you have a list of all the classes that your code defines then you may be able to use one of the above mentioned methods (`ReflectionClass::getTraits` for instance) and then compare the traits, the class uses, against the trait that you are looking for. You would have to load all the classes in your application, however, which is not very efficient or practical.

If you can limit your search to a small subset of your classes then doing something like this may work reasonably well.

I wonder why you feel like you need to do something like this, however. It is not something people generally do. It is odd.

Comment: Yes, it's odd, but funny enough I have the same issue right now, where I thought about the op question as well. In my case, I have a namespace with App\ for all my code. But now I started to move it away and split everything into Modules\ up. This leads to the problem, that I can't resolve class just by it's class name...